# mean mode for sparse data

Tags: standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

I have a larger list of numbers of which the majority is 0. Thus the mode is 0. However the mean is also misleading IMHO. Which summary statistics are appropriate in such situations?

Comment: *Why* are they misleading?

Answer (score 1):

If zero is the "normal" value, I would find the mean of the non-zero values. Then summarise the data as ...
The mean as above,
The number of non-zero values as a percentage of the total number of values.